# How to handle over-prediction in Random-Forest

Tags: r, random-forest

I have a regression Random Forest model (generated using H2O and R). After tuning and building the model, I plot the predicted value vs. the labeled value of both the train and test datasets. In a model with zero errors I'd expect it to align with the 45-deg line. In my plot a get a line which is paralleled to the 45-deg line, but not aligned to it.
From the plot I concluded that the model pick up the general trend, the slope, correctly, but it's biased in terms of absolute values.
I'm a little confused on how to address it. I tried both parameter tuning and enlarging the train dataset, but in vain. 
Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks!

[image: The prediction vs. labeled plot]

Comment: Once approach would be to split your data into a training set, calibration set, and test set.  Fit your random forest on the training set, use the predictions on the calibration set + a linear regression model to learn an adjustment to the random forest, and use both models to predict on the test set.

Comment: What does your fitting equation look like? Is it regularized?

Comment: @bey what do you mean by fitting equation? What I did was to take my training set and put it in the model - and comparing it to the real values.

Comment: You need to know how it's fitting your random forest. What quantity is it minimizing to identify the solution? This is critical to know if you hope to address any questions about your findings or are doing diagnostics..